# Login over AJAX on Flask-Login

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, flask-login

When I try to perform a over ajax login ('/login') with user and password, it does loggin, but when I try to get the user data after login current_user is Anonymous.
I have 3 routes:

- /login: POST parameters user and password. The router takes the user and password and does the login.
- /user: RETURN user data (name, email) if the user is logged in else 404
- /logout: GET performs a logout

/user and /logout wont work cause the user is not logged in when I $.get this routes.

API routes (login, user, logout) are on 'localhost:5000' while front-end ReactJS is on 'localhost:3000'.

My user loader:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.get(user_id)
    except:
        return None
```

/login route:

```
@view.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=request.form['email']).first()
    if user and check_password_hash(
            user.password, request.form['password']):
        print(login_user(user, remember=True))
        response = jsonify(user.serialize)
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        return response
    else:
        return 404
```

/user route:

```
@view.route('/user', methods=['GET'])
def get_user():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        response = jsonify(User.query.get(current_user.id).serialize)
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        return response
    else:
        abort(404)
```

In /user after I logged in current_user is AnnonymousUserMixin.

What am I missing here?